# Setting instance variables with ActiveScaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers, activescaffold, instance-methods

I've recently added ActiveScaffold to an existing Rails project, and the problem I'm having is that the variable names that ActiveScaffold is using are not the same as the ones I already have. Rather than going through my entire application and changing all of the instance variable names, I'd like to be able to set the instance variables in the controller. The problem is that `@record` and `@records` cannot be called in `before_filters`, even if the `before_filter` is after the `active_scaffold` call.  Looking through the plugin, I see no obvious hook inside of the `ActiveScaffold::Actions` modules. I'm wondering:

1. Is there such a hook?
2. If not, how should I put one in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way to do this is to overwrite the do_show, do_create, do_list, etc... methods in the controller.